# Setting file path to a project to be deployed in a GlassFish Server via web project in Java

Tags: file, web, glassfish

I have a project and I do some file read-write processes to get some values about glassfish server responses.
For example, in a write process, I declared my file like this :

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "D:\\stajyer\\Glassfish Deployment\\out.txt"));
```

It's okay when I'm working on my local jetty server. But this project will be used as web project in other computers, this is a problem. There won't be this file in their path. 
So what should I do to solve this problem? 
How could I embeed my text file into my project?

P.S: In D:\stajyer\Glassfish Deployment\out.txt, Glassfish Deployment is my project's name.

Thanks for help, I tried to be spesific as much as I could.

Comment: What is the problem with including the out.txt in your project?

Comment: It is already included in my project. But it is an absolute path, so another user computer maybe don't have this file. I don't know how to include this text file to deployed file in server.
Sorry if I couldn't be clear.

Comment: If the file is included in your project it will also be in the WAR file...just put the file in your WEB-INF folder or in `src/main/resources`.